# How to pass everything from a command into a function with escaped characters

Tags: command

These are my scenarios and expected output

```
function! s:Foo(text)
    echoerr "'" . a:text . "'"
endfunction

command ... FooCommand ... (not sure what to write here)

FooCommand text
```

> 'text'

```
FooCommand text asdfsfd
```

> 'text asdfsfd'

(it's hard to see in stackoverflow but the next one has trailing whitespace)

```
FooCommand line with 4 trailing spaces
```

> 'line with 4 trailing spaces    '

```
FooCommand line with"quotes" here
```

> 'line with"quotes" here'

Nothing that I've tried works. I've tried `<f-args>`, `<q-args>`, `<args>` and I've tried manually adding `""`s around the non `q-` versions. They all fail for some reason or another.

Either the function will say it didn't `get enough args`, `Undefined variable`, or including `"`s will cut off text at the first double-quote that's found.

The best combination I got was my first try - Use `<q-args>` and then manually escape `"`s all the time. But even then, `<q-args>` doesn't seem to allow trailing whitespace. So I can't use it for what I'm trying to do.

Is there any way for Vim to just let me pass everything as one big string to a function and it just escape everything properly? Including quotes. Including spaces. I just want Vim to take whatever I write and put it in a  string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add `-nargs=1` to your command:

```
:command -nargs=1 FooCommand :call Foo(<q-args>)
```

This tells Vim not to treat white space as separator. Only white space between the command name and the first non-white space character is removed from the argument passed to `Foo()`. All other spaces and tabs, even trailing ones, are included in the argument.

Comment: Okay, that's definitely it. Thank you for your help. I tried this initially but got tripped up because I also included `-bar` in the command definition. If you do `:command -bar -nargs=1 FooCommand :call Foo(<q-args>)` then Vim errors with "E471: Argument required". Do you know how to make this work with -bar as well?

Comment: Okay, I think the reason is because `-bar` enables commenting. So Vim thinks that the quoted text `""` is actually the start of a comment. I haven't figured out a way around it but it would at least explain why the function thinks it isn't getting any args

Comment: `-bar` is primarily there to allow a user-defined command to be followed by another command, e.g., `:FooCommand Hello World | echo 'I just fooed "Hello World"'`. A nice side effect of this is, that the second command can be an empty command with a comment, which can be used to comment the first command: `:FooCommand Hello World | "I just fooed 'Hello World'`.

Comment: I understand that. I wanted support for `|` which is why I originally included `-bar`. But as mentioned before, `-bar` changes the way `"`s are interpreted and causes a string to be interpreted as a comment. Also, even without any `"`s in the input, `-bar` removes trailing whitespace (third example in my original post). Is there a way to get the same functionality as before but including `-bar`?

Comment: If you add `-bar` to the command definition you will have to escape both `|` and `"` with a backslash (and, of course, backslashes, too), e.g., `:FooCommand \"Hello \| World\" | echo 'I just fooed "Hello | World"'`. Trailing whitespace will again be removed, though, and it seems it cannot be protected with backslashes.

Comment: But what do you want to achieve? Do you really need to follow `:FooCommand ...` with another command? Wouldn't it be easier to call the function directly and pass a single-quoted string?

Comment: Honestly there's not that much of a need. I could do the command followed by another. My use case is search and replace, basically `:MyCoolQuickFixCommand "def " | cdo %s/def /chef/g`. I had to write my own search function because the files are highly proprietary at my company and spread across multiple folders and files include other files recursively.

Basically I was hoping for something idiomatic. What you've shown me gets me most of the way there (thank you for your help so far, by the way).